# Fat tail threshold

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How 'fat' do tails have to be to be give a distribution undefined variance? Is there an inequality for the kurtosis of the distribution which determines this? No matter how fat the tails, they must converge to the axis as the distribution must enclose a finite area of 1 (kind of reminds me of Gabriels horn...)

Comment: Remember that variance gives extra weight to large deviations. This "fattens" the tail, which can turn a tail with finite area but somewhat fat tail, into a tail with infinite area.

Comment: I have been pondering your question for a couple of days, wondering just how much additional background information you may need. My answer gives examples with links that should answer additional related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one straightforward example look at Student's t distributions with 2 and 3 degrees of freedom, respectively. The variance is not defined for DF=2, but is defined for DF=3. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) on t distributions.)

The PDF of Student's t distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom has
density function of the form $f(x)=K(1 + \frac{x^2}{\nu})^{-(\nu + 1)/2},$ where $K$ is the constant that makes $f(x)$ integrate to $1$ over the real line.

- For $\nu = 1,$ this is a Cauchy distribution which has a median, but no mean.
  That is, $\mu=\int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx$ is an [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral); multiplication of the PDF by $x$ makes the tails of the integrand 'too fat' for a properly convergent integral.
- For $\nu = 2,$ the mean is $0,$ but multiplying the PDF by $x^2$ leads to
  an improper integral, so that the second moments do not exist.
- For $\nu > 2,$ both $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2 = \frac{\nu}{\nu-2}$ exist.

For somewhat similar examples with convergent and divergent infinite
series for *discrete probability distributions,* you may want to look at
[zeta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution#:%7E:text=Zeta%20distribution.%20where%20%CE%B6(%20s)%20is%20the%20Riemann,thus%20as%20the%20normalization%20of%20the%20Zipf%20distribution.) based on the Riemann zeta function (linked from there).